# Ember: adding a mixin to a class after it's been created

Tags: ember.js, mixins

I want to add a mixin to an Ember class which has already been created. (The class is defined in a library, actually Ember itself; it's `LinkView`).

I see that we can do `mixin.apply(obj)`, but this applies the mixin to an *instance* of the class. I want to add the mixin to the class, so it's automatically mixed-in to all newly created objects.

I attempted to override the `init` method of the class, using `reopenClass`, and do `mixin.apply(this)` there, to apply the mixin to the instance, and then call the original `init` method, but this does not seem to work because the mixin wiring is set up in the `init` method and it's already too late by the time I can get to it.

`reopenClass` does not seem to accept a mixin argument like `extend` does. Its code seems to suggest that it's doing something with mixins, but whatever it is it doesn't work:

```
a = Ember.Object.extend().reopenClass(Ember.Mixin.create({mixval: 1});
a.create().get('mixval'); // undefined
```

I know that I could create my own class with `MyLinkView = Ember.LinkView.extend(mixin, ...`, but unfortunately the original class name is referenced explicitly within the library, so I really would prefer to figure out how to extend that original class with my mixin.

I experimented with `Ember.LinkView = Ember.LinkView.extend(mixin, ...`. This somehow seems dangerous, although it seems to work. But in this particular case it doesn't help me since the reference within the Ember code (in the definition of the `{{link-to}}` helper) is to an internal version of the class, not the fully qualified `Ember.LinkView`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is simply

```
Klass = Parent.extend({init: {...}});
Mixin = Ember.Mixin.create({init: {...}});
Klass.reopen(mixin);
```

Everything works as expected, including the super chain. In other words, a call to `Klass.create().init()` will call the mixin's `init`, and a call to super from there will call the original `Klass#init`.

In the course of researching this question, I discovered something interesting about `reopen`. Even if the argument is not a mixin, it is treated as one (internally, it actually creates a temporary one). This means that if you do

```
Klass.reopen({
  init: function() {
    this._super.apply(this, arguments);
  }
});
```

The call to `super` is actually calling the original `init`, not the `init` in the parent class. In other words, specifying `init` in a `reopen` does not *replace* the existing `init` on the class, it more or less *layers* on top of it. I can't see this behavior documented anywhere in the Ember docs, but it does seem useful in the right situation.